# How to use =sum function properly in excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

In the above picture, for the column G7, I wan sum of D7, E7, F7. So, I am using =sum(D7:F7), but excel is showing error for the formula by highlighting a green flag. If I ask it to correct the formula on its own, it changes it to =sum(C7:F7), but that's not what I want. How to tackle this issue?

Of course, if I change the formula to =sum(D7,E7,F7), problem gets solved but what exactly is the problem with =sum(D7:F7)?

Comment: Are you getting an actual error or just an information flag?  Excel sometimes over-functions for your "benefit".  Your formula excludes an adjacent numerical value.  Excel, in its infinite benevolence, could just be alerting you to a possible oversight, since it knows humans are prone to stupid mistakes.

Comment: that's some malevolent benevolence! Guess I'll just ignore the error if that's the case. (no actual error, just information flag. but I get distracted and alarmed by it. I hope my evaluator won't deduct marks for these flags!)

Comment: You could add your own flag, flagging the misinformation in the alert flags.  Of course that would probably trigger more alert flags that Excel thinks you might not be doing your flag right.

Comment: @fixer1234 do you have any sources or documentation for this? It would be good information to have as an answer, though I've never run into it. My first thought was that this was a table or some other type of grouped information in order for that to happen.

Comment: @Raystafarian - Just returned and found your comment.  I see it's overtaken by events.  Looks like CharlieRB and you already did a good job of covering this.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the function properly. Excel is using `error checking` to warn you there may be cells which need to be included.

[Excel Help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-common-errors-in-formulas-f3bc671f-17fe-4793-a3f7-7833a711a7ca) states:

> **Formulas which omit cells in a region** - A formula might not
>   automatically include references to data that you insert between the
>   original range of data and the cell that contains the formula. This
>   rule compares the reference in a formula against the actual range of
>   cells that is adjacent to the cell that contains the formula. If the
>   adjacent cells contain additional values and are not blank, Excel
>   displays an error next to the formula.

In the image below I have invoked the error checking because only selected 3 of the 4 adjacent cells for the formula. There is nothing wrong with the formula itself, but Excel is warning me I may have missed a cell.

[image]

If you know your formula is correct, you can choose to ignore the error and the green flag will go away.